# ASP.NET How get a custom header in a Request?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

I have a simple question. I set a custom header like this:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
string urlWebApi = "urlOfMyApi";
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(urlWebApi);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
string token = "valueOfToken";
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Token", token);
```

How get the value of header "Token" in my Api?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your API Controller, you should be able to access the HttpRequest which has a "Headers" property which is a collection of Key/Value pairs, so you can get it like this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage SomeControllerAction()
{
    return Request.Headers["Token"]
}
```